# Is it possible to sign all print jobs coming out an HP Laser Jet 3015 printer?

Tags: printer, network-printer

Is it possible to sign all print jobs coming out of a network printer? i want to print the user id of the user who requested the print job on the footnote of the every document that comes out of the printer, i found no way to this using the Operating System (Windows 2012 R2) all my research just kept redirecting me to the print log.

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way to achieve what you want is to use "Separator Pages". That will print out an additional page before each print job. This extra page can be made to show user name, file name, etc.

To activate Separator Pages, go to Printer Properties, click the Advanced tab and then the Separator Pages button. I suggest using the file PCL.SEP as it's the easiest to modify. You can find it in %WINDIR%\System32. Edit it with any text editor, including Notepad. You can find the syntax of the file on [Microsoft's Knowledge Base](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/102712). Notice that the parameter @N will print the username.

If you want to add the username on the printed page (and, as fixer1234 says, corrupt the printjob), consider using Watermarks. According to the [manual](http://www.manualslib.com/manual/71115/Hp-3015.html?page=52), the LaserJet 3015 supports it, from the Effects tab in Printer properties.

Another possibility is the use of Printer Management software. Google "Printer Management software" to find a package that suits your needs. However, most of them cost real money, as they do a lot more than just identifying a user, and their reason for existence is to save on company printing costs.